# How do I create a dict inside a for loop? python

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop, indexing, slice

I'm working with an api that returns a large list of dictionaries when the function is called. For example it returns this format

```
[{'label':'def'},{'dict2_label':'dict2_def'},{'etc':etc}]
```

The solution I'm using to retrieve the data is like this

```
for _ in list_of_dicts: 
    data1 = _['label']
    data2 = _['dict2_label']
    etc
```

Finally I print the data I want like this

```
print('data1', data1, '\n', 'data2', data2, '\n', etc)
```

is there a way I can collect the data I want out of the for loop(or any other method that would extract the data) so I don't have to define every variable? cheers

Comment: You can extract only the data with something like ```[next(iter((i.values()))) for i in api_res]```

Comment: Are you extracting the same keys from every dict? If not, how do you know which key is used for which dict?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract specific results with labels by building up a dict:

```py
results = {}
for item in list_of_dicts: 
    results['data1'] = item['label']
```

and later process it further or print it out:

```py
for key, value in results.items():
    print(key, '=', value)
```